# how can I get the id of dynamically created checboxa

Tags: jquery

Create dynamic checkbox

```
function parseXml(xml) {  
$(xml).find("sterowniki").each(function() { 
var i = 1;
$(xml).find("items").each(function() { 
$( "#pierwszy" ).append(' <div class="row"><div class="checkbox"><label><li class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10"><a href="produkt.html?id='+i+'">'+$(this).attr('name')+'</a></li><input class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" type="checkbox" name="porownaj"  value="stery"></label></div></div>');     
i=i+1;
});
});
```

Do checkbox is also thanks to broadcast id, or do I have to give it separate. And how to reach it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).on()` for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.row .checkbox label input[type=checkbox]', function(){
  // do something
});
```

Read about `.on()` here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is not going to have an automatically assigned id. By default it has no id at all.

If you need to id, you can explicitly give it one.

```
var $checkbox = $("<div>").addClass("checkbox").attr("id", "your id").appendTo($parentElement);
```

But there's a chance you don't need it.. If you just want to reference it, you can create it like this:

```
var $checkbox = $("<div>").addClass("checkbox").attr("add attribute here", "value").appendTo($parentElement);
```